# Error using "append" mode with Pyspark saveAsTable method

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm able to write my dataframe as a hive table this way:

```
mydf.write.format("parquet").saveAsTable("mydb.mytable")
```

But when I'm trying to append the same data in the same table using "append" mode like this:

```
mydf.write.mode("append").format("parquet").saveAsTable("mydb.mytable")
```

I get an error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o106.saveAsTable.
: java.util.NoSuchElementException: next on empty iterator
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:39)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$2.next(Iterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqLike$Elements.next(IndexedSeqLike.scala:63)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.head(IterableLike.scala:107)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.scala$collection$IndexedSeqOptimized$$super$head(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.head(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:126)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.head(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$18.apply(DataSource.scala:466)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$18.apply(DataSource.scala:463)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.planForWritingFileFormat(DataSource.scala:463)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeAndRead(DataSource.scala:516)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableAsSelectCommand.saveDataIntoTable(createDataSourceTables.scala:216)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.CreateDataSourceTableAsSelectCommand.run(createDataSourceTables.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:656)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.createTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:458)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:437)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveAsTable(DataFrameWriter.scala:393)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

No idea why I'm getting this. Please help

Thanks

Comment: What Spark version are you using?

Comment: @Gooseman. Im using :
Spark 2.3.0.2.6.5.3016-3, 
 Hive 1.2.1000.2.6.5.3016-3

Comment: Are you using Hortonworks?

Comment: Did you solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it by setting the "header" option to "true".

Example:

```
df.write.format("orc").option("header", "true").mode("append").insertInto("db.table")
```

Hope it helps someone in the future

Answer (score 0):

It's worth to make sure the table has been created before appending new records by a simple SQL code:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM mydb.mytable")
```

In addition, there is no need to set the file format as it has been defined already. So if you update your code to the following line it should work smoothly.

```
mydf.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("mydb.mytable")
```

Update:
I tested the same scenario without getting an error message. These are the steps I took:
[Code and result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hC3xR.jpg)

You could have access to the [Google colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AWqJl8L7oPmGYlU3h_8so-RSyLtj7Ag9?usp=sharing) that I just created for this test.

I hope this help

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work. Still same error.
 Defining the same format anyway shouldn't cause the error. It's something else

Comment: I updated my answer, I tested the same code with no error message. Could you test your code in Google Colab to make sure the code itself is correct? I think the issue is in your installed pyspark or cluster you are using.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your effort, but you're not writing to hive. Im getting the issue while writing to hive.